# Want to get details of place by clicking on the marker which are stored in HashMap

Tags: android, json, hashmap

This function stores the json data in hashmap.

```
  private Map<MarkerOptions, JSONObject> markersMap = new HashMap<MarkerOptions, JSONObject>();



private void parseLocationResult(final JSONObject result) {

    String id, place_id = null, placeName = null, reference, icon, vicinity = null,location;
    JSONArray rev;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    try {
        final JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray(RESULTS);//JavaScript Object Notation

        if (result.getString(STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(OK)) {

            mMap.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject place = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                id = place.getString(SUPERMARKET_ID);
                place_id = place.getString(PLACE_ID);
                if (!place.isNull(NAME)) {
                    placeName = place.getString(NAME);
                }
                if (!place.isNull(VICINITY)) {
                    vicinity = place.getString(VICINITY);
                }
                latitude = place.getJSONObject(GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(LOCATION)
                        .getDouble(LATITUDE);
                longitude = place.getJSONObject(GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(LOCATION)
                        .getDouble(LONGITUDE);
                reference = place.getString(REFERENCE);
                icon = place.getString(ICON);


                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                markerOptions
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bluemarker))
                        .position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);


                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                markersMap.put(markerOptions,place);


            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonArray.length() + " found!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (result.getString(STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(ZERO_RESULTS)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not found in 5KM radius!!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "parseLocationResult: Error=" + e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Now this in this function I want to get the details which are stored in the hashMap. Later on i will call this function(ShowDetails) in previous function(parseLocationResult).
I have declared json object. Now kindly tell me how i can get details in ShowDetails Function which are stored in hash map through function parseLocationResult.

```
 public void showdetails(final Place place)


{
    final JSONObject jsonObject=markersMap.get(markersMap);



    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();


            editor.putString("_PlaceID", place.getId());
            editor.putString("_name", (String) place.getName());
            editor.putString("_address", (String) place.getAddress());
            editor.putString("_webUri", String.valueOf(place.getWebsiteUri()));
            editor.putString("_PhoneNo", (String) place.getPhoneNumber());
            editor.putString("_Lat", String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude));
            editor.putString("_Lng", String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude));

            editor.putString("_rating",String.valueOf(place.getRating()));
            editor.apply();











            Intent i=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,infoWindow.class);
            startActivity(i);

            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
private Map<MarkerOptions, JSONObject> markersMap = new HashMap<MarkerOptions, JSONObject>();
```

to

```
private Map<Marker, JSONObject> markersMap = new HashMap<Marker, JSONObject>();
```

and then store Marker in your map like this:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markersMap.put(marker,place);
```

Later you can retrieve your Json like this:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        JsonObject markersMap = markersMap.get(marker);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting error on "mHashMap" in OnMarkerClick(Marker marker) function.

Comment: it was my mistake in name, change name to your hashMap name (markersMap)

Comment: now where should i use markerMap which is a jsonobject in onMarkerClick because  it is still unused.

Comment: @ZiaAnsari use markersMap (the jsonObject in onClickMarker) to obtain your data!!! what you want to get in onMarkerClick?

Comment: can you write me a sample code please. I want to get the data of places which are shown on the map. for Example: If I click on A restaurant it should show me the details of the restaurant A, When i click on restaurant B it should show me the places of restaurant B etc In InfoWindow,.

Comment: I have done so far...thankyou very much.....but markerMap is coming null in markerClickListener